# Create a tar.gz file and transfer it to network server

Tags: python, backup, raspberry-pi3

I have a Raspberry pi running on my home network along with a Macintosh that acts as a backup server.  I am attempting to craft a Python3 script that will run on the Pi to create a tar.gz backup of the Pi's home folder (along with all of the contents) and transfer it to the Macintosh using SSH.  I have the SSH connection (using keys) running but am stumped when I try to create the backup file and transfer it.

My code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import paramiko
import tarfile
import os

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connnect(hostname = '192.168.1.151', username = 'usernamehere')

print("I'm  connected!")

#The following statement is the problem as I see it

tar czvf -  ./home/PiOne/ | ssh_client -w:gz "cat > ./Volumes/PiBackups/PiOne/PiOneClone.tar.gz"

print("File transferred!")

ssh_client.close
```

I would appreciate any help in creating the script!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something easier to transfer a file from your VM to your local machine. Also that you are using SSH

```
scp -i /path/your/targz/file user@ip:/path/to/local/machine
```

Check permission while doing that using

```
ls -lh
```

Comment: I checked and thanks for the code - it works.  I was hoping to create the tar.gz file and transfer it in one step.  Is that possible?  Or would I have to create the tar.gz file and store it locally and then transfer it using scp and then delete the local file?